# Find a vector space and a set without Tschebyschev center.

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, approximation, numerical-optimization

I have such exercise:
Give example of a vector space G and its subset A such that the center of A does not exists.

By the Tschebyschev center we mean the center of the smallest ball containing A ( that ball's radius is called radius of set A).

I spent 2 hours on thinking and havent got it yet.
I think it must be infinite dimentional vector space, otherwise center exists. I thought about spaces known from functional analysis like L1,l1,c,c0,c00, but was unable to find an example.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think you must first give as an hypothesis that $A$ is a **bounded** set

Comment: There is a good book that contains many "Counterexamples in Analysis" (Gelbaum and Olmsted): https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a4e7/eb352e4c44bf75d8fabaf7594494151cb322.pdf Maybe not for what you are looking for, but in general, you can browse this book and learn many things...

Comment: This [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1998896?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) may be useful to you as it gives examples of sets with no Chebyshev center.

Comment: @JeanMarie I realised myself that A must be bounded. Otherwise, every point is a center. I treated it as obvious so I did not write it.

Comment: Thanks @CarlChristian that example seems legit.